# The change of the distribution of a sample mean when n reaches infinity

Tags: statistics, means, law-of-large-numbers

[image]

Hi guys, I posted this question yesterday, but I deleted it because I didn't clarify it. Now I am posting with the picture attached. Is the following correct?

I think it is correct, because if the sample is really large, then the distribution of the mean would converge to the expected value. But how to elaborate it in a more formal way? Or maybe someone can prove that it is not true. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not true.

The normal distribution can take on an infinite number of values, yet the sample average for a rando sample drawn from a population whose measurements follow this distribution (e.g., height to a good approximation) will have non-zero variance.

The question is not about the size of the sample, but about the size of the *sample space*. Two completely different concepts. Your statement about large sample properties is generally correct for distributions with finite mean. However, there is no "Law of Large Sample Spaces" that would make the statement true.

Comment: Hi, would you mind taking a look at the answer below, he has a different answer than yours.

Comment: @J.doe its not correct. They are making the same mistake you did. The question is not saying "as the sample size gets larger" its saying "as the sample *space* gets larger". Two completely different things.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I know if a problem is referring to sample size or sample space?

Comment: @J.doe the sample size is the number of samples you draw from a population. The sample space refers to the number of possible values that each sample point can take.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!! Can you help me with this question also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926156/the-powers-of-odd-moments?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It is true.</strike>

For the sample you'll get some standard deviation, $\sigma$.

The standard deviation of the mean is $${\sigma}_m = \dfrac{\sigma}{n^{0.5}}$$

where $n$ is the sample size. So as $n$ goes to infinity the standard deviation of the mean converges to zero.

Comment: question is stating "as the number of *possible values* gets large..." not "as the sample size gets larger". Also, its trying to apply the Law of Large Numbers to a population as opposed to a sample from that population. That would be like applying the LLN to the Normal Distribution...doesn't make sense.

Comment: You're right I misread the question, even after reading your answer.