# If $Y$ is symmetrically distributed around $E(Y)$ then $E(Y^j)=E(Y)^j$ for every odd $j$, why not for $j$ even?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, means

In this statement "If a random variable Y is symmetrically distributed around its mean $\mu_Y$, that is, $Y=\mu_Y+U$, where U is symmetrically distributed aronud zero- then the odd moments of Y are powers of $\mu_Y$, i.e. $E[(Y)^j]= (\mu_Y)^j $ for any odd integer j, assuming the moment exists".

I think this statement is true for both even and odd moments. What is the significance of the odd moment? And is it true when it comes to the even moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: All you need to know is that $U$ is symmetrically distributed with zero mean. This implies that all odd moments of $U$ will be 0.

So, we know that

$$E[(Y-\mu_Y)^3]=E[Y^3 -3 Y^2\mu_Y+3 Y\mu_Y^2-\mu_Y^3]=0 \implies$$
$$ E[Y^3] =  E[3 Y^2\mu_Y-3 Y\mu_Y^2+\mu_Y^3]=3 \mu_Y E[Y^2]-3 \mu_Y^2 E[Y]+\mu_Y^3 \implies $$

$$E[Y^3]= 3 \mu_Y E[Y^2]-2\mu_Y^3  $$

This value depends on the value for $E[Y^2]$, which we can derive as follows:

$$Var[Y] = E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2 \implies E[Y^2] = Var[Y] + \mu_Y^2$$

However, $Var[Y]=Var[U]$ so

$$E[Y^2] = Var[U] + \mu_Y^2$$

So, assuming $Var[U]>0$, what can you conclude?

Comment: If $Var[U]$ is really small, does that imply they are equal?

Comment: @J.doe Sorry, meant to write the opposite.

Comment: Oh I got it. When it comes to the even power, it depends on the value of $Var[U]$, if it is large, then this statement is only validate for odd powers. But if it is small, then this statement works for both odd and even powers?

Comment: @J.doe The statement is either correct or not. My suggestion was to help point out a potential issue for even powers. As for odd powers: my hint implies that $E[(Y-\mu_Y)^3]=0$. What does this imply about $E[Y^3]$. Try to work out math with the moments.

Comment: Because the moment is 0, so $E[Y^3]$ is also 0, which suggests that they are equal. Is this correct?

Comment: Got it! So the statement is true when it is odd powers, correct?

Comment: @J.doe see my revised post. I gave more substantial hints

Comment: Then $E[Y^2]$ is not the same as $\mu_Y^2$. Thus the odd powers are not equal as well.

Comment: Thank you so so so so much!!!

Comment: @J.doe no prob. mark as accepted if you found it helpful.